# ErrorException chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) when trying to create a laravel project

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I try to create a new Laravel project I get this error:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./blog"
Installing laravel/laravel (v8.4.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v8.4.0): Extracting archive
Created project in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog


  [ErrorException]
  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)
```

I'm using XAMPP by the way.

Comment: you should check for some antivirus, the folder the project is creating is getting deleted maybe by external interference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
composer self-update
```

Answer (score 1):

## In window

When you install composer,
please choose the option "for only me".(for administrative purpose).
don't choose the option "all users".
if you choose the option "all users", you will get the installation error that is "chdir():No

Such file or directory, errno 2" when you install laravel through composer (command from

laravel offical documentation,"composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog").