# Error when trying to install Laravel Via Composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-8, laravel-9

I already have Composer and XAMPP installed.
But when I try to use `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app`  command to create a new project by using Composer directly I throws some errors

```
C:\Users\HP>composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./example-app"
Installing laravel/laravel (v9.1.10)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v9.1.10): Extracting archive
Created project in C:\Users\HP\example-app

In CreateProjectCommand.php line 497:

  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]


C:\Users\HP>
```

I have tried:

1. Reinstalling Composer
2. Changing folder where I want to create my project
3. Using the `composer global require laravel/installer`
   I'm using Composer version 2.3.7 and PHP Version 8.1.6. Im trying to install laravel 9 and my XAMPP is version 3.3.0

Comment: Have you tried to create a new project with the command Laravel new projectname ?

Comment: why not `composer global require laravel/installer` and then `laravel new example-app`

Comment: I did this and I still get the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
composer self-update
```

[Same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64731414/14856989)

Or you should change your installation directory.

```
cd desktop
```

Comment: yes, composer self-update says "You are already using the latest available Composer version 2.3.7 (stable channel)." and when I cd to desktop I still get the same errors